# Why is there no indefinite article before the word hall?

Tags: grammaticality

The usage of the word 'hall' listed in [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hall) sounds a bit odd to me and I can't wrap my head around how it could be grammatical.

> 4. hall [british]: A university building containing rooms for students to live in.
>
>    > for a brief time they had shared a room in hall
>
> 4.1. The room used for meals in a college, university, or school.
>
> > he dined in hall

Comment: As a native speaker (American) it doesn't sound grammatical to me, either. If I had to guess, it's a relative of "in hospital".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is similar to saying "I studied at school" or "I went to hospital". Institutions sometimes use a zero article, and "hall" is an institution of some universities. It is the residential aspect of the university, providing food and sleeping space for students. For some of the older universities, your degree has residential as well as academic requirements. In the past you needed to be in hall for a certain number of nights to qualify for your degree.

However it is a rather rare use of the word "hall". It is not used in American English, and you are unlikely to see it unless you are talking to students from some of the older universities. Using "On campus" is a good alternative to "in hall" that is more widely used.

Comment: One might use "on campus" in a similar style in America.

Comment: That would also be good British English, and probably more common.

Comment: From my experience studying at Cambridge in the 1970s,  4.1 is very familliar: "In Hall" means "in the specific room in college known as "Hall" - it is effectively a proper name. However, I don't recognise meaning 4. at all. If this expression was ever used in Cambridge, it was obsolete before the 1970s.